# extjs TreeStore proxy with dynamic update api

Tags: ajax, json, tree, extjs4

From my extended Ext.data.TreeStore:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: "/GetTree.json",
        update: "/SetTree.aspx?username=user1"
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'children'
    },
    listeners: {
        exception: function (proxy, response, options) {
            // error case
            console.log('Exception in Portlets store proxy...');
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
},
```

What I am trying to figure out is how can I make the `username=user1` dynamic, such that I could pass in `user2` and have the aspx page process with that user data.

I cannot figure out if/how `TreeStore.sync()` allows parameters to be passed into it.

### Update:

What I am really after here is the ability to save back the entire tree structure as a JSON string instead of just the record that was updated. I can build the JSON string I need to pass but cannot figure out how to actually get that information to my `SetTree.aspx` page.

Comment: you could loop through all records and mark them dirty. by would you want to do that really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting extra params on the proxy before calling sync:

```
store.proxy.extraParams = { param1 : '', param2 : '' };
```

There is anecdotal evidence that suggests this works in 4.1.3 but not earlier versions.

Another thought is to just fire a regular Ajax.request and send desired params along instead of using the tree store to do that.

Comment: I just ended up using a jQuery Ajax request and hid the `markDirty` indicator on the tree panel. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Example?

Comment: I get it now. If I could figure out how to post a code block here I'd show you what I came up with. Used the `Ext.Ajax.request({...` to do what I was with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but for people like me that were searching for the same question...
If you want to save the entire structure instead of just the modified lines, you need to define a `writer` in your store proxy and in that writer, set `writeAllFields: false`:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: "/GetTree.json",
        update: "/SetTree.aspx?username=user1"
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'children'
    },
    listeners: {
        exception: function (proxy, response, options) {
            // error case
            console.log('Exception in Portlets store proxy...');
            console.log(response);
        }
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    }
},
```